# How to use SSH to run a shell script on a remote machine?

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, scripting, sudo

I'd like to execute some sudo privilege commands using bash script from local to remote server via ssh without passing multiple commands separating from semicolons on ssh.
I've tried below step but got error.

```
ssh -t user@remoteip 'bash -s' < services.sh
```

Though I've used -t option here it still shows error message.

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

Comment: The missing tty can easily be allocated with `ssh -t`. The basic problems are (1) that you are not _running_ a script, you are _sourcing_ it, which is very different sometimes, and (2) `sudo` will want to authenticate you, but your input is redirected to the script.

Comment: Learn Ansible - https://www.ansible.com/ and you'll be happy you did.

Comment: Use `ssh -tt` to force the tty allocation, but make sure that sudo will not ask for a password, if sudo ask for a password it will return control to the tty for password input and will fail there. If you can not set sudo without password your only option besides ansible or similar is to use expect and have your password in clear text which is not good at all.

Comment: assuming your sudo commands are allowed for your username, under which you will run them and have a NOPASSWORD directive with them, my suggestion is not to run them from a local script with a redirect, like you did in the question, but write them to a file, copy the file to the remote server using `scp` and run them as `ssh remote-machine-name /bin/bash -x /path/to/copied/script/file`

Comment: I'm still stuck on **sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo** error though I followed your step @MelBurslan

Answer (score 3):

This can occur when `Defaults    requiretty` is uncommented in `/etc/sudoers`.

The fix is to comment that line:

```
#Defaults    requiretty
```

Remember to only edit `/etc/sudoers` using the `visudo`** command.

**The `visudo` command may only be run by the `root` user.

Comment: It will not be possible to change sudoers file in every server manually. Is there any alternative solution for that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as well:

```
ssh -t user@remoteip <<'EOF'
command1
command2
command3
EOF
```

Although it would probably be best to save the script with the commands you want on the remote machine and just call it once you log in.

Comment: I also wanted to call the script full of commands but still stuck on the error.